# why value of head changes in main and in function?

Tags: c, linked-list

Head pointer pointing to different nodes in function and in main. why?

```
#include<stdio.h>

#include<stdlib.h>

      struct node{

    int data;

    struct node *link;

};

int insert_node(struct node *head){

    struct node *ptr=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    struct node *temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    ptr->data=12;
    ptr->link=NULL;
    ptr->link=head;
    head=ptr;
    temp=head;
    while(temp!=NULL){
            printf("\n%d",temp->data);
            temp=temp->link;
    }
    printf("\nHead in fn=:%d",head);
}

int main(){


    struct node *head=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    head->data=56;


    struct node *current=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    current->data=78;

    head->link=current;

    struct node *current1=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    current1->data=45;

    current->link=current1;


    struct node *current2=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    current2->data=69;
    current2->link=NULL;
    current1->link=current2;
    insert_node(head);
    printf("\nhead in main-:%d",head);



    return 0;
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KudzR.png

Comment: you set `head=ptr;` ....

Answer (score 0):

Arguments of functions in C are *copies* of what are passed. Modifying arguments in callee functions doesn't affect what are passed in caller.

In this case, the `insert_node` function assigns a new value to `head` and prints that. The change doesn't affect `head` in the `main` function and the original value is printed in `main`.

Also note that you are invoking *undefined behavior* by passing data having wrong type to `printf()`. `%d` is for printing `int`. To print pointers via `printf()`, you should cast them to `void*` and use `%p`.

Comment: so what should i do in order to fix the code?

Comment: Have `insert_node` tell the new value of `head` to the caller. It can be done by returning the new value or receiving a pointer to `struct node*` and write the new value to where the pointer points at.